# Authenticate Samba using Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, samba

Background: 
We have a samba file server using `security = user`, authenticating users in local linux, works great.
We migrated our cloud solution to Office 365, which includes a Azure AD.

Question:

Is that possible to Samba authenticate users in Azure AD and map to local linux users?

I wouldn't like to join samba as domain member, actually, don't even know if it is possible, too cumbersome.

I'd like a simple solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the note of the offical document [Overview of Azure Active Directory authentication over SMB for Azure Files (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview), as below, it seems to be impossible for authenticating Samba with AAD although this document is for Azure File Storage.

> Azure AD authentication over SMB is not supported for Linux VMs for the preview release. Only Windows Server VMs are supported.

However, a workaround way I think is to combine a LDAP with Azure AD and then to authenticate Samba with LDAP. You can try to refer to the documents below to know how to do.

1. [Configure secure LDAP (LDAPS) for an Azure AD Domain Services managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap)
2. [LDAP-based authentication for Samba](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/tutorials/l-ldapsamba/index.html)

As above, it seems to be not a simple solution. Maybe you need to consider for your scenario using Samba to develop a web application with Azure AD authentication.

Comment: I believe that may have a way to authenticate against AAD in another way, without using the default schema, maybe writing a Samba auth plugin or something. I want a simple solution, without LDAP if possible. Thanks!